# 'GroupSingle' object is not callable

Tags: python

I`m writing my first solo pygame game. Everything is going well I'm able to get through most things but this problem has really stumped me. It was when I programming animations for a sprite where I encountered this bug.

```
#Imports
import pygame
import random
import math
from sys import exit

pygame.init()

#Classes

class shield_cursor(pygame.sprite.Sprite): # Creates the class shield_cursor
    def _init_(self, mx, my): 
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) # Initialises a basic sprite class
        self.mx = mx # mx is the mouses x position
        self.my = my # my is the mouses y position
        self.rect = shield_cursor_rect # Takes the rect and makes it part of the class

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def _init_(self):
        super()._init_()
        player_walk_1 = pygame.image.load("Shield_knight_body1.png").convert_alpha()
        player_walk_2 = pygame.image.load("Shield_knight_body2.png").convert_alpha()
        player_walk_3 = pygame.image.load("Shield_knight_body3.png").convert_alpha()
        player_walk_4 = pygame.image.load("Shield_knight_body4.png").convert_alpha()
        player_walk_5 = pygame.image.load("Shield_knight_body5.png").convert_alpha()
        self.player_walk = [player_walk_1, player_walk_2, player_walk_3, player_walk_4, player_walk_5]
        self.player_index = 0

        self.image = self.player_walk[self.player_index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom = (100,100))

    def animation_state(self):
        while player_moving == True:
            if self.player_index >= len(self.player_walk):
                self.player_index = 0
            self.image = self.player_walk[int(self.player_index)]

    def update(self):
        self.animation_state()

    

#Declaring values
screen_width = 800
screen_height = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))                              screen.pygame.display.set_caption("Shield Knight")
test_triangle_red_colour = (255, 0, 0) 
test_triangle_blue_colour = (0,0,255)
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
player_moving = True

#load images
backmap = pygame.image.load("shield_Knight_map.png").convert() #Saves the map`s file as background
shield_cursor_basic = pygame.image.load("shield_Knight_cursor.png").convert_alpha() 

#Adding groups
player = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
player.add(player())

#Main game loop
running = True #Shows the code is running
while running:
    sea_rectangle1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, test_triangle_red_colour, pygame.Rect(0,0,100,800))
    sea_rectangle2 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, test_triangle_red_colour, pygame.Rect(700,0,100,800))
    sea_rectangle3 =pygame.draw.rect(screen, test_triangle_blue_colour, pygame.Rect(100,700,600,100))
    sea_rectangle4 =pygame.draw.rect(screen, test_triangle_blue_colour, pygame.Rect(100,0,600,100))
    sea_rect1 = sea_rectangle1
    sea_rect2 = sea_rectangle2
    sea_rect3 = sea_rectangle3
    sea_rect4 = sea_rectangle4
    screen.blit(backmap, (0,0)) # Draws the background

    player.draw(screen)
    player.update()

    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos() # Assigns mx and my to the current mouse positions and is constantly updating
   screen.blit(shield_cursor_basic, (mx, my)) # draws the shield on the mouses x and y position
   shield_cursor_rect = shield_cursor_basic.get_rect(topleft=(mx,my)) # creates a rect around the shield for collisions
   pygame.mouse.set_visible(0) #Makes the mouse invisible

    if sea_rect1.colliderect(shield_cursor_rect): # Checks if the test rectangle collides
        pygame.mouse.set_pos([100,my])
    if sea_rect2.colliderect(shield_cursor_rect): # Checks if the test rectangle collides
        pygame.mouse.set_pos([650,my])
    if sea_rect3.colliderect(shield_cursor_rect): # Checks if the test rectangle collides
        pygame.mouse.set_pos([mx,650])
    if sea_rect4.colliderect(shield_cursor_rect): # Checks if the test rectangle collides
        pygame.mouse.set_pos([mx,100])
    
    for event in pygame.event.get(): #Getting an event from pygame
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #Checking if the quit button is clicked 
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

    pygame.display.update() #Makes the screen constantly update.
pygame.quit() #Exits the screen
```

PS sorry if the code is inefficient or messy.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Shield_Knight\Shield_knight.py", line 59, in 
player.add(player())
TypeError: 'GroupSingle' object is not callable

Error message

I expected the code to boot up as per normal and for the animations to be permanently cycling through (testing as the code isn`t finished). However it gave the error message that group single is not callable.
I tried adding a capital P to player.add(player()) in the second player and it was a very diffrent error message.

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to call `player` as a function but it is a `pygame.sprite.GroupSingle` object.

Lets add an instance of the Player class to the group, and also you used `_init_` method instead of `__init__` method.

```
#Imports
import pygame
import random
import math
from sys import exit

pygame.init()

#Classes
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        player_walk_1 = pygame.image.load("Shield_knight_body1.png").convert_alpha()
        player_walk_2 = pygame.image.load("Shield_knight_body2.png").convert_alpha()
        player_walk_3 = pygame.image.load("Shield_knight_body3.png").convert_alpha()
        player_walk_4 = pygame.image.load("Shield_knight_body4.png").convert_alpha()
        player_walk_5 = pygame.image.load("Shield_knight_body5.png").convert_alpha()
        self.player_walk = [player_walk_1, player_walk_2, player_walk_3, player_walk_4, player_walk_5]
        self.player_index = 0

        self.image = self.player_walk[self.player_index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom = (100,100))

    def animation_state(self):
        global player_moving
        while player_moving == True:
            if self.player_index >= len(self.player_walk):
                self.player_index = 0
            self.image = self.player_walk[int(self.player_index)]

    def update(self):
        self.animation_state()

#Declaring values
screen_width = 800
screen_height = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))                              
screen.pygame.display.set_caption("Shield Knight")
test_triangle_red_colour = (255, 0, 0) 
test_triangle_blue_colour = (0,0,255)
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
player_moving = True

#load images
backmap = pygame.image.load("shield_Knight_map.png").convert() 
shield_cursor_basic = pygame.image.load("shield_Knight_cursor.png").convert_alpha() 

#Adding groups
player = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
player.add(Player())

#Main game loop
running = True
while running:
    sea_rectangle1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, test_triangle_red_colour, pygame.Rect(0,0,100,800))
    sea_rectangle2 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, test_triangle_red_colour, pygame.Rect(700,0,100,800))
    sea_rectangle3 =pygame.draw.rect(screen, test_triangle_blue_colour, pygame.Rect(100,700,600,100))
    sea_rectangle4 =pygame.draw.rect(screen, test_triangle_blue_colour, pygame.Rect(100,0,600,100))
    sea_rect1 = sea_rectangle1
    sea_rect2 = sea_rectangle2
    sea_rect3 = sea_rectangle3
    sea_rect4 = sea_rectangle4
    screen.blit(backmap, (0,0)) 

    player.draw(screen)
    player.update()

    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    screen.blit(shield_cursor_basic, (mx, my))
    shield_cursor_rect = shield_cursor_basic.get_rect(topleft=(mx,my))
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(0) 

    if sea_rect1.colliderect(shield_cursor_rect):
        pygame.mouse.set_pos([100,my])
    if sea_rect2.colliderect(shield_cursor_rect):
        pygame.mouse.set_pos([650,my])
    if sea_rect3.colliderect(shield_cursor_rect):
        pygame.mouse.set_pos([mx,650])
    if sea_rect4.colliderect(shield_cursor_rect):
        pygame.mouse.set_pos([mx,100])
    
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame
```